# "out of" vs. duplicated "from"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can we use the word "from" (again) instead of "out of" in the following sentence? Does it not make sense if we use or it was not used in order to avoid repeating the word from ?

> ...Here's the formal definition from the ABC Institute out of their
>   book called...

---

How about this sentence

> ...Here's the formal definition from  their book called...

Comment: Both sentences are ok, not repeating words if an alternative is available is often done but not mandatory. A question of style, not grammar. In short: You are absolutely right.

Comment: 'out of their book' sounds very awkward to me. If you want to avoid the double 'from', how about 'in their book' ?

Comment: @Tetsujin actually the first sentence is a original sentence from a video in English.

Comment: @Murat - people also say "off of the telly" even though it's become a national joke in the UK ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I see , it could be awkward. It is a lecture from a American university. Could it be more American dialect?

Comment: It's one of those things that, in speech, no-one would even notice. It's only when written down that you start to analyse it

Comment: (Native AmE) I agree that "out of their book" sounds awkward here, though it is a legitimate synonym and it could sound normal in other situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s grammatically correct to repeat the word “from”, like this:

> Here’s the formal definition **from** the ABC Institute **from** their book *The World’s Best-Loved Formal Definitions*: …

However, as you probably guessed, it sounds a little clumsy. English provides many alternative ways to say the same thing. Here are a few examples:

> Here’s the **ABC Institute’s** formal definition **from** their book *De Ratione Definiendi Æquivocando*: …
>
> Here’s the formal definition **from** the ABC Institute, **found in** their book *From Genus, From Differentia*: …
>
> **Quoting** *A Child’s First Book of Definitions,* here’s the **ABC Institute’s** formal definition: …

More generally, here’s how to think up alternatives to fix a repeated or unclear preposition: (1) see if you can use the possessive case; (2) think of something *more specific* to say in place of the preposition. As the examples of “found” and “quoting” illustrate, the new word will often be a verb. That suggests another strategy: (3) think of a verb.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, it is perfectly fine to replace 'out of' with 'from' in this case. If you were to do so in conversation, it's likely that no one would care or notice. In writing, we often try to avoid repeating a word in that way, and will use different phrasing or a synonym to avoid it. This is purely a stylistic decision, however.